# How to redirect to seo friendly url using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, seo

In my web application htaccess is able to translate seo friendly urls of the form

```
/e-dmis/home  
/e-dmis/system-admin/groups      
/e-dmis/system-admin/standard-lists/accounting/COA
```

....
....
TO

```
/e-dmis/index.php?content=home  
/e-dmis/index.php?content=system-admin/groups  
/e-dmis/index.php?content=system-admin/standard-lists/accounting/COA
```

....
....

However I am caught in a situation where I need to redirect to page using jquery.For example,

```
var root = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
window.location.href=root+'/e-dmis/home';
```

To my suprise,**`window.location.href`** is always taking me to the index page,that is,`/e-dmis/index.php`- removing the 'content' parameter.
You assistance will be greatly appreciated as it will shorten hours of googling on web about this.
**Here is the .htaccess file:**

```
Options -MultiViews
# Turn on rewriting
RewriteEngine On
# Starting with /e-dmis
RewriteBase /e-dmis
# If there's no file that matches the request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# *nor* a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?content=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The browser doesn't have any notion of the server-side URL rewriting, hence I find it dubious that it would work even without the redirection. I suggest you use a debugger to retrieve the exact URL you're building and assigning to `location.href`, load it manually in your browser to verify that (1) the issue isn't related to redirection and (2) that it's built correctly, and review your server logs for more information. Unless I'm wrong, it is likely that your rewrite rules are problematic -- if so it would help if you posted them.

Comment: @tne I have tried to load it manually and they are working except for /e-dmis/home. e-dmis/home changes to e-dmis/home/index.php and I think this should be the root of the whole matter. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I'm not comfortable giving advice on .htaccess URL rewrite, though I suggest you add a tag for your web server (Apache?), the "rewrite" tag, and possibly others. You should also remove the php, jquery and possibly seo tags as they don't seem relevant. This should help attract more knowledgeable people. Just a quick suggestion though: verify that you don't have an *actual* `/home` directory that would somehow take precedence over the rewrite rules.